# Chainlink- Issue when fetching an API in form of `bytes32`

Tags: api, chainlink

I've been learning the chainlink API and trying to modify the [example](https://docs.chain.link/docs/advanced-tutorial/) from the Chainlin's documentation to get a `byets32` value from an API. The original code of the example works well, but since the API I was hitting is returning a `byets32` foem, the Chainlink job need to be configured to handle this type of return. The node is given [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/decentralized-oracles-ethereum-mainnet/) with Kovan testnet. Here is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
     //Result of the api
     bytes32 public martket;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Get -> bytes32
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
     * Node)
     * Job ID: 7401f318127148a894c00c292e486ffd
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        // Get -> bytes32 node taken from documentation
        oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8;
        jobId = "7401f318127148a894c00c292e486ffd";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "MARKET": "CCCAGG",
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        
        //Get the MARKET field of API
        request.add("path", "RAW,ETH,USD,MARKET"); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format
        
       
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of bytes32
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _market) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        martket = _market;
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

The value of `market` should be a `byets32` reprsenting "CCCAGG" as shown in the API. But what I got was just `0x0...00` all the time, which means `market` has not been modified yet. I've checked this various ways and found out that the `fulfill` function never get rans. Then same thing happens when I changed the `jobId` and `oracle` to handle `get-> int256`, `get -> bool` (of course I did change the return type of the variable such that it's consistent with the returning form of API). I also noticed that only the job `get -> uint256` works well (the example from documentation also used this job). Does anyon know why? Was my code wrong or the problem came from the node/job? Since I was able the get the example right, I don't think the problem cam from my wallet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: there's currently some internal discussion going on regarding the get-bytes32 jobs on the new TOML job format. When I have more clarity, I'll respond with a proper answer. But in the meantime, as a workaround you can use the 'large respones' solution for returning any length of byte data https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/

Comment: 1. It looks like your jobid may not exist anymore. To find a live job, try https://market.link
2. "CCCAGG" string may not be converted to bytes32, because its length is not equal 32.

Answer (score 0):

You can test with a GET>STRING JOB

1. Go to this link: https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api-testnet-oracles/
2. Take the Oracle contract address relevant to your network. For instance: 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7 for Goerli
3. Use a Get>String job: 7d80a6386ef543a3abb52817f6707e3b

Make sure that your callback function expects to receive a string. (see a full example here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/api-array-response/)