# Chainlink: Contract cannot retrieve large-response data type from external adapter

Tags: chainlink

I tried to use the `large-response` type to fulfil the request but somehow it does not show up in my contract I tried to fulfil the `status` value, and the job works completely as shown in my chainlink node but it does not change the `status` value, it stays `0x` as it is. So, I wonder that is my contract or job spec wrong?

This is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";


contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    bytes public status;
    string public statusString;
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestFulfilled(bytes32 indexed requestId,bytes indexed data);
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
     * Node)
     * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0xDFE5e6C5C624724384b55719b7da79d3EbB60057;
        fee = 1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    function requesData(string memory _jobId) public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("trackingNo", "HF123456789DL");
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bytes memory bytesData) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        emit RequestFulfilled(_requestId, bytesData);
        status = bytesData;
        statusString = string(status);
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract


    // function getStatus() public view returns (string memory) {
    //     return bytes32ToString(status);
    // }

     function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32)
        public
        pure
        returns (string memory)
    {
        uint8 i = 0;
        while (i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(i);
        for (i = 0; i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0; i++) {
            bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
        }
        return string(bytesArray);
    }

        function stringToBytes32(string memory source)
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes32 result)
    {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }

        assembly {
            // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }


}
```

This is my job spec.

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Halffin-Data-EA-Create-Tracking8"
externalJobID = "3f706a6b-efdd-44ac-8167-f880a6ca63ac"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "0xDFE5e6C5C624724384b55719b7da79d3EbB60057"
minIncomingConfirmations = 0
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name="halffin-data" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"trackingNo\\": $(decode_cbor.trackingNo)}}"]

    parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,tracking,slug" data="$(fetch)"]

    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(bytes value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]

    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0xDFE5e6C5C624724384b55719b7da79d3EbB60057" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

- These are logs from completed job

fetch

```
"{\"jobRunID\":\"3f706a6b-efdd-44ac-8167-f880a6ca63ac\",\"data\":{\"tracking\":{\"id\":2,\"slug\":\"halffin-logistics\",\"tracking_number\":\"HF123456789DL\"},\"result\":null},\"result\":null}"

name: halffin-data

requestData: {"id": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), "data": { "trackingNo": $(decode_cbor.trackingNo)}}
```

parse

```
"halffin-logistics"

path: data,tracking,slug

data: $(fetch)
```

encode_data

```
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001168616c6666696e2d6c6f67697374696373000000000000000000000000000000"

abi: (bytes value)

data: { "value": $(parse) }
```

encode_tx

```
"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"

abi: fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes data)

data: {"requestId": $(decode_log.requestId), "payment": $(decode_log.payment), "callbackAddress": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), "callbackFunctionId": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), "expiration": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), "data": $(encode_data)}
```

submit_tx

```
"{\"logs\": [], \"root\": \"0x\", \"status\": \"0x0\", \"gasUsed\": \"0x5c49\", \"blockHash\": \"0x5b55db677b2776bb637fdb9ba2077e7db21de8e8beba60fb79e1384ae51f39a8\", \"logsBloom\": \"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\", \"blockNumber\": \"0x1d94cd5\", \"contractAddress\": \"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\", \"transactionHash\": \"0xc5371c5ce1692b39835e44fb61c47d2deeeb509f71e32fccb0c5d42eec3be443\", \"transactionIndex\": \"0x1\", \"cumulativeGasUsed\": \"0x39418\"}"

to: 0xDFE5e6C5C624724384b55719b7da79d3EbB60057

data: $(encode_tx)
```

In case, you might wonder why I use the `large-response` data type. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71745260/chainlink-issue-when-fetching-an-api-in-form-of-bytes32)

Comment: It looks like the job is running but it's receiving a '0' as the response.

Can you double-check the bridge and external adapter to ensure they are returning the correct value to the node when requested?

Comment: Yes, I tested with uint256 value, and it received correctly

Answer (score 0):

The `contractAddress` specified in the `(Get > Large bytes)` must be pointed at `operator.sol` not `oracle.sol`. `(Get > Uint256)` is pointed at `oracle.sol`. `Oracle.sol` is not meant to handle Large bytes, nor multi-variable Uint256 output.

Here is the code to deploy the current version of `operator.sol` on remix to then obtain the correct `contractAddress` to the associated job-spec within the chainlink node GUI.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol";
```